# Правда ли, что "абракадабра" — заклинание?

Tags: этимология

В литературе мне попадалось упоминание о том, что изначально слово "абракадабра" было каббалистическим заклинанием. Но, если так, каким образом оно попало в русский язык?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.romver.ru/my/print.php?razdel=44 
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0 
Как и все остальные знания - через общение со знающими  людьми и книгами: Ветхим Заветом, древними книгами заклинаний и пр.